# Navigation between nested navigator between Stack and Swtich Navigator in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Hi i have navigation that has **RootNavigator** as follows;

```
const App = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: AuthNavigator,
    App: HomeNavigator,
    Seller: SellerNavigator
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Auth",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);
```

**Scenario**

> **Auth** contains login ,signup etc . **App** contains home,etc.   When user is logged in ,he is now **App Navigator**.
>
> What i want when user press Logout ,i want to **move user properly
>   from App navigator to Auth navigator**

i have tried out [StackNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset]) and [NavigationActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)

**Code**

```
logout = () => {
        const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            key: null,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Auth'})]
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
};
```

**Error**

[image]

**Please guide me how to do it properly in react navigation ?**

thanks

Comment: for using navigation actions you have to wrap the component in navigation tag before exporting it!

Comment: how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use stack actions there because `Auth` is not part of the stack navigator.

What you can do is simply `navigation.navigate('Auth')` from the logout component. This will take the user in the `Auth` navigator and since `Auth` and `App` are part of the switch navigator he will not be able to `go back` to the `App` stack which is the behaviour you want, in this case, it is the same as using `StackActions.reset`.